# ERROR IN MYSQL QUERY DATEDIFF() FUNCTION

Tags: sql, mysql

I am trying to calculate duration. I am using MySQL 5.0 but I am getting this error

```
1305 - FUNCTION smgm.DATEDIFF dose not exist
```

My query is:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF (MI,timein,timeout)/60 as duration 
FROM User_smgm
where ID=2;
```

my database name is SMGM

Any Idea why is this so? Where as when I try simple DATEDIFF it's working fine. Such as I tried

```
SELECT DATEDIFF('2008-11-30','2008-11-29') DURATION
```

Answer (score 1):

The `datediff` function in MySQL gets the difference in days. There is no overload where you can specify a time period. Use the `date_sub` function instead.

Answer (score 0):

> DATEDIFF (MI,timein,timeout)

why do you have three arguments in datediff?